# jQuery timepicker time format not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

I have a timepicker form element:

```
<input type="text" name="start_time" class="timepicker" placeholder="Start Time*" required>
```

which I'm trying to format but it's not working:

[image]

I followed the [documentation](http://timepicker.co/options/) and added `timeFormat` like so:

```
  $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '8:00 am',
    maxTime: '11:30 pm',
    startTime: '8:00 am',
    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
    dynamic: true,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
  });
```

So I don't understand why it's not working. Any help would be appreciated!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbkbvym2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation posted by you it's not the same as in [jquery-timepicker documentation](https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker). Then your timeFormat should be: `timeFormat: 'h:i a'`.

Somewhere on that documentation is written that the format uses the php date format: [php date](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: I want to select hours and minutes separately, It has time interval of half hour I don't want this, how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

For me i what worked was using tt for the format of the time. All others were not rendering on my page no matter what i did it was 24hr format. Here each element has a class of timepicker

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.timepicker').timepicker({
               timeFormat: 'h:mm tt',
                startTime: '8:00 am',
                dynamic: true,
                dropdown: true,
                scrollbar: true
            });
        });                      
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you want I believe:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
</head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.5/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.timepicker').timepicker({
          timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
          interval: 30,
          minTime: '8',
          maxTime: '11:30pm', 
          startTime: '08:00',
          dynamic: true,
          dropdown: true,
          scrollbar: true
      });
    });
    </script>
<body>
    
<input type="text" name="start_time" class="timepicker" placeholder="Start Time*" required>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions suggested anywhere worked for me, so I checked the source of the timepicker I`m using (listed as jquery.timePicker.min.js) and find the formating is done with: `show24Hours: true/false` i.e.

```
                         $('.weekdays').timePicker({   
                                startTime: "08:00", 
                                endTime: "22:00",
                                show24Hours: false,
                                step: 30                  
                        });
```

There appears to be no option in this timePicker to avoid leading zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready({
    $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
        change: function(time) {
            // the input field
            var element = $(this), text;
            // get access to this Timepicker instance
            var timepicker = element.timepicker();
            text = 'Selected time is: ' + timepicker.format(time);
            element.siblings('span.help-line').text(text);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi sandeep agarwal, welcome. Please consider adding more information.